# Substitution (re.sub) in Python

Tags: python, regex

Folks,
I come from TCL background and kind of beginner to Python Automation. I tried to read about the usage of regular expression in python and didn't find it to be different when compared to TCL way of doing things.

I am stuck with a problem wherein i have a table output which i need to parse, but before which i need to remove/substitute some text which i don't which to parse.

```
output="""
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
R4               Ser 1/0            139         R S I     3725      Ser 1/0
ESW1             Fas 0/1            149          S I      3725      Fas 0/1
"""
```

I need to remove all the text from the first line untill it matches Repeater and substitute it with whitepsace.

The way i used to do it in tcl was like this.

```
regsub -all {^.*Repeater} $output {} newoutput
```

I am trying the below code in python but its not helping me.

```
output=output.strip(' \t\n\s')
sub_output=re.sub('.*Repeater',' ',output)
```

Need help on this. Also if there is any document which explains the usage of flags in regular expressions in Python

Comment: What *exactly* are you trying to accomplish? It looks like you're trying to remove the line that contains `Repeater`. If this is the case, forgo the regex and simply parse this line-by-line. Your problem statement is unclear.

Comment: *How is this not helping?* Also, `\s` is not an escape sequence. It is a metacharacter in regex, but `str.strip` doesn't interpret regex metacharacters.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem statement is not clear, but I'm going to assume you're trying to extract the "meat" from this network device's output.

First, we can use `str.splitlines()` to easily iterate over each line of output.

Normally, we could then just `str.split()` each line to get each whitespace-separated item. However, some of your information itself contains spaces (e.g. `Ser 1/0`). So instead, we'll use [`re.split()`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.split) and indicate that we want to split on  *at least* two spaces.

```
import re

def parse_table(output):
    found_header = False
    for line in output.splitlines():
        if line.startswith('Device ID'):
            found_header = True
            continue

        if not found_header:
            continue

        yield re.split(' {2,}', line)

sample_output="""
Capability Codes: R - Router, T - Trans Bridge, B - Source Route Bridge
                  S - Switch, H - Host, I - IGMP, r - Repeater

Device ID        Local Intrfce     Holdtme    Capability  Platform  Port ID
R4               Ser 1/0            139         R S I     3725      Ser 1/0
ESW1             Fas 0/1            149          S I      3725      Fas 0/1
"""

from pprint import pprint
pprint(list(parse_table(sample_output)))
```

**Output:**

```
[['R4', 'Ser 1/0', '139', 'R S I', '3725', 'Ser 1/0'],
 ['ESW1', 'Fas 0/1', '149', 'S I', '3725', 'Fas 0/1']]
```

#### Additional reference:

- [Python Regular Expression Syntax](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax)

Comment: Thanks for the response Jonathon, The end result was to parse the output and get it in a list or a dictonary and your code rightly does that . But what i actually wanted to know was how using re.sub() we can substitute the remove the first two lines and replace it with some text of my choice or whitepsace